# Ask the user to create a new question after being asked in comments

Tags: discussion

I'm new to this community and I'm not sure if my behavior was correct, so I'm asking.

I have answered a question, and in the comments the user asked me another question, related but different, which I tried to solve responding as a comment but it was too long to be posted, so I ended up telling him that he should create a new question about it because I also considered it to be useful for the community. Was it right or what should I have done?

This is the referred [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552661/can-linear-conflict-heuristic-cause-more-nodes-to-be-created-and-explored-than-m).

Comment: You have done the correct thing. Whether it is **intentional or not**, this may lead to sucking out every ounce of goodwill you may have - as long as you are answering, the OP is happy. In the really bad cases they may even make threats to downvote or not or un-accept. See also Meta SE's excellent overview in [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: Yes, the general rule of one question per question should apply.  If the OP asked in a comment for clarification of your answer, then you can edit the clarification into the answer.

Comment: You are awesome and you did the right thing.  SO is like being at a bar, but no alcohol.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Yes, your behavior was correct**.

Questions in answer comments fall into one of two categories:

- They point out some problem or ask for clarification about your answer. In that case, it should be fixable by editing your answer.
- They pose a different (but related) question. The line between this and asking for clarification can be blurry. But when the question is definitely outside the scope of the original question, and too complex to answer in a short comment, telling the questioner to post it as a new question is the correct way to go about it.

Answer (score 8):

I've encountered that a few times and it really is up to you what you do, but here is how I handle it.

1. If it is just a question about applying the answer and doesn't really improve the answer any ("So, if I wanted to sort by first name instead, I'd use this other sort key?"), I will go ahead and answer with a comment (provided it is short enough).
2. If it somehow adds to the answer but is on topic (it might broaden the answer, but not exactly answer a new question), I'll edit an answer into my other answer sometimes adding a comment that I am adding to the answer based on new questions from the OP (my example in case 1 is probably better handled under this case).
3. If it doesn't fall into either (1) or (2), I'll ask the OP to post a new question and to link me to the question if I think that I'll be able to answer it.  If it builds on the one that I just answered, I'll ask them to incorporate their chosen solution into their code for the new question ("So, what if I wanted to capitalize all names after I sorted them?").