# Latest guidance for case where user asks unrelated question in a comment on an answer?

Tags: support, comments

It seems like a fairly common occurrence for new users to post unrelated questions in comments to answers. I sometimes get these on my own answers, and I just found another one on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45485198/126352

I know there's a "flag comment" feature but the guidance I've seen suggests (although not necessarily definitively) that flagging in cases like this should be limited to egregious cases or repeat offenders. For example, here's [2014 guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254816/126352) from [@BoltClock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock), implying that flagging shouldn't be the first line of defense:

> If a user keeps veering off-topic in comments, flag the offending
>   comments and remind them to stay on-topic and to avoid lengthy
>   conversations.

Furthermore, there's no flag for "new question" (or anything like it) in the comment-flagging reasons.

So, now that I found this off-topic comment, how should I handle it?  Should I flag it as "It's no longer needed."?  Flag it as "Something Else"?  Or should I just comment with a recommendation that the commenter should open a new question?

The latter recommendation is what I found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318274/126352):

> when the question is definitely outside the scope of the original
>   question, and too complex to answer in a short comment, telling the
>   questioner to post it as a new question is the correct way to go about
>   it.

But this 2-year-old recommendation was before the last year's flurry of "make SO nicer for newbies" work so I was wondering: is "add your own comment" still the right approach to deal with unrelated questions in comments?

If it is, then:

- Is there a well-tested (for newbie-friendliness) template language for how these kinds of comments should be written?  I tried a few drafts and had trouble finding the right tone that was encouraging to the user without being rude or (just as bad!) encouraging back-and-forth argument about whether the question was really unrelated. (Although users with 3K rep should know better, so maybe a little unfriendly might be OK in this case, although I'm still curious about the more common case where question in comments come from newbies)
- Is the SO team already looking at a way to automate this kind of "ask a question instead!" feedback with friendly text and usability-tested UX, like we do with duplicate questions and other minor violations of SO etiquette where we want to gently teach newbies what to do without driving them away and without adding work for moderators?  If not, then I'll open a feature request! ;-)

**UPDATE:** Looks like there isn't canonical language for this case. In the interest of helping others avoid re-inventing the wheel, here's what I wrote:

> [username redated] - your follow-up question about Date runtime
>   behavior is not closely related to the answer above which is focused
>   on TypeScript typings. Therefore, it's not likely that you'll get this
>   question answered here. If you ask a new SO question, you'll likely
>   have more success getting it answered.

Comment: Human communication requires both listener and speaker. Make your best effort. If it's not well-received, move on to something else more constructive. There's little fulfillment to be found in worrying that someone else on the internet thinks that you're wrong.

Comment: How is the guidance not nice or friendly to newbies? You're showing them how to get their new question answered, while also explaining how the site works. 'be nice to newbies' isn't about giving them 100% of what they ask...

Comment: @Patrice - The guidance isn't nice or not-nice, that's up to me in how I write the comment. I was just wondering if adding another comment was still the recommended approach like it was in 2016, and if yes then I was wondering if there is canonical language documented for this case. Since it sounds like there isn't, I wrote my own. (see updated question)

Comment: I prefer to keep it simple: "It seems your current question was answered. If you have a new question, please post it as such." (*disengage*)

Comment: I think the reason used in Low Quality Review Queue for "different question posted as an answer" can be used as a guideline (replaced "answer" with "comment")

Comment: "it seems like comment flagging is discouraged except in egregious cases or repeat offenders" [citation needed]

Comment: Hi @Braiam - I added a mod citation from 2014 as one example. Other answers to the same question imply similar process. Nothing definitive, though, just my reading of what was being implied. Also there's Servy's answer below. ;-)

Comment: Your source actually recommends the opposite "comments **should always be relevant** to the question or answer at hand". If they aren't relevant, you are to flag them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you feel that you're not capable of being polite in a response to such a comment telling them that they should ask a new question, then your remaining options are to either ignore it entirely, or flag the comment as no longer needed (because it's not needed on that post).  If you feel that you can remain polite in telling the commentor that they should ask a new question, then by all means do so.

If you see a pattern of behavior in which a user is *repeatedly* commenting on your post with additional questions to an extend that it is becoming disruptive to you, then feel free to use a moderator flag to explain that there is a pattern of behavior here that is becoming disruptive to you, and they can take it from there.