# User Edits Post And Leaves Threatening Comment

Tags: support, edits

I've got [a Python answer about `urllib`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28052583) that has been around for a couple of years.

A few edits have been made in that time and I've not had a problem with them, but I've just had an edit that came with the following comment:

> Removed highly dangerous advice for monkeypatching. It can unknowingly affect all downstream users of the package. The answer will be flagged for deletion if the monkeypatching advice is restored.

I was going to revert the edit as it was clearly stated that this advice came from [PEP476](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/) and was highly discouraged. Now I'm not so sure what the correct response is.

Should I just leave the edit and move on? Or am free to revert and just ignore the threat?

Comment: You're free to do revert it. do flags for deletion even exist? a vote for deletion isn't even possible for that answer. At worst it'd be a mod flag, and a mod will dismiss it because mods don't judge correctness.

Comment: Revert, and flag if they remove it again.

Comment: A good reminder of why there's no "delete" flag...

Comment: The advice in the answer really is extremely dangerous. It can lead to all kinds of security nightmares and million dollar problems. I stand by what I said.

Comment: Cast your vote, leave your comment, move on.

Comment: @A-B-B You're free to stand by what you said, but could you at least provide a little justification as to why? The OP has a solid reference from PEP476 citing why what they suggested is a good idea, and you're just saying some vague "security nightmares" claims with no backup.

Comment: Related, on the topic of security problems in answers: [Problematic PHP cryptography advice in popular questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293930) [Fixing answers that recommend chmod 777](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318885)

Comment: @Noelkd I recommend at least adding a comment to your answer noting that monkeypatching should only ever be done in an end-user application, and never in a reusuable package or library.

Comment: I mean... the answer *already* states it is highly discouraged. Isn't it more useful to include it and state it's highly discouraged than to remove it altogether? If other users find it and disregard that warning, that's on them.

Comment: @KevinB There are some situations in which it's more discouraged than in other situations. For example, using it in a reusable library would be an absolute no. If a system administrator was instead using it in an isolated application, that's less discouraged. The answer fails to make this distinction.

Comment: @DavyM [PEP476](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/#opting-out) notes that only sysadmins may monkeypatch, and not libraries. The answer by Noelkd fails to note this distinction.

Comment: @A-B-B: "*I stand by what I said.*" Regardless of the technical merits of your edit reason, it is *never* OK to threaten someone as you did. Even though your threat couldn't be followed through (since any flag you tried to use would be denied), making such a threat goes outside the bounds of acceptable behavior.

Comment: @NicolBolas There is nothing wrong with warning a user of a flag. The user has demonstrated willful negligence by not adding the warning recommended by Shog9 into the answer.

Comment: @A-B-B: "*The answer by Noelkd fails to note this distinction.*" If you felt that the bold-face "highly discouraged" statement was not sufficient of a warning, why did you not simply add a more explicit warning?

Comment: @A-B-B "The answer by Noelkd fails to note this distinction." I disagree. They noted that the monkeypatch is highly discouraged, and they referenced PEP476 - the same source you just referenced to note that only sysadmins should patch, and not libraries. In my opinion, the distinction is made clear in the answer and your tone is wholly uncalled for.

Comment: @souldeux I doubt you appreciate how many noob readers copy and paste the monkeypatching code without understanding the gravity of the damage they're doing. They very much need a clearer warning of what goes wrong. It's like asking someone to not do narcotics saying narcotics are highly discouraged, as if that's ever going to work. People need to be told exactly what goes wrong and under which scenarios. The distinction is not made in the answer.

Comment: @NicolBolas I should have. It didn't occur to me at the time. There is just little reason to use the monkeypatching code since other calls can be modified instead to more selectively use an unverified SSL context.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Please stop bickering in the comments section. Everyone's had a chance to make their point of view known. If you want to share your opinion further, post an answer in the big box below.

Comment: @CodyGray Two users have just gone on a vengeful downvoting spree for three of my recent questions. I request you or another moderator investigate who did it. There is no rational reason for such a spree. I myself have never done anything so nasty. I also request this question be closed so as to prevent any further vengeful acts. Those questions and their answers are very specialized, and it would be a pity to lose them due to excessive downvotes.

Comment: @A-B-B I'll have a look. In the future, please raise a private flag for issues like this. Pick one of your posts that has been downvoted, click the "flag" link, and use the "needs moderator attention" textbox to express your concerns. One of us will look into it. That said, beware of drawing unsubstantiated conclusions. You don't know who is downvoting your posts, or why they're doing it. Better not to accuse, but just ask for someone to see if anything suspicious might be happening.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is like a "Choose Your Own Adventure" game. Broadly speaking, you have two choices, which depend on your answers to a series of questions:

1. **Are they right?** Sure, they presented their advice in a rather threatening and unproductive manner, but maybe they just have [the social skills of a thermonuclear device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040217-00/?p=40583). If their advice is nevertheless correct, then you must decide:

   1. **Does their edit improve your answer? Are you satisfied with their presentation?**

      - If so, then you're done. Leave it alone and move along, chalking it up to some weirdo on the Internet who just did you and everyone else [a weird sort of favor](https://xkcd.com/386/).
      - If not, but they are still technically correct, then you should edit your answer to a form that satisfies you, but still conveys the same useful information.
2. **Are they a crank?** Social skills aside, this person has no clue what they're talking about and has just taken a massive dump on your answer. That's not good. Not only do you not want incorrect information ascribed to your name, but you don't want incorrect advice promulgated on this website. So, roll back their edit, reversing the damage. Then decide:

   1. **Are you threatened by the edit message? Is it completely inappropriate, or do you want to let it slide?**

      - If you feel threatened, then raise a flag for moderator attention. We'll look into it, and then use our best judgment (or, sometimes, our pretty-good judgment, but never our worst judgment, or even our acceptable judgment) to decide how to follow up with the editor.
      - If you're just annoyed, then let it go, hoping that the person will move on and find something else to do in their free time. If they don't, and they carry through on their seemingly-idle threats, *then* raise a flag for moderator intervention, and we'll be a bit more stern in our approach.

Just to be clear, as [Kevin B](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380460/user-edits-post-and-leaves-threatening-comment#comment672101_380460) and [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380460/user-edits-post-and-leaves-threatening-comment#comment672104_380460) have already said, moderators don't judge answers for technical correctness. There is no "delete" flag; there is no "this answer is wrong" flag. Answers are only deleted because they fundamentally don't meet [our guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) (they aren't attempts to answer the question, they consist of nothing more than a link, they are plagiarized, etc.), not because they are wrong. We aren't experts in every programming language under the sun, so we couldn't do this even if we wanted to.

As [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will), *moderator emeritus*, [used to say](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103545/a-sock-with-28-rep-points-just-deleted-my-comment):

> Moderators are janitors. You flag us when someone throws up in the hallway. We are not professors, tasked with grading answers to questions. If someone provides an unsatisfactory answer, downvote them, leave a comment, or provide a better answer. Do not flag the answer as "unsatisfactory." There is nothing a moderator can (or should) do about a [wrong] answer.

Comment: Upvoted for linking to the best blog on the planet, aka Raymond Chen's.

Comment: That "social skills of a thermonuclear device" musing should be the first thing every new user sees when they come here.

Answer (score 61):

So, that's an unnecessarily confrontational comment...

But let's ignore that for the moment. Confrontation is the language of our time, and *many* people struggle to separate "necessary" from "unnecessary".

What's useful in that comment is this:

> It can unknowingly affect all downstream users of the package.

That's obvious if you know what monkeypatching is... But perhaps some readers will not. So a short addition to your answer to the effect of,

> Warning! This will poison ALL uses of SSL in the application where it is used - *no* contexts will be verified! Use only after a thorough review by all developers, and do not use in libraries or other code that may be included in 3rd-party applications.

...or some such would not be amiss. And then advise the editor that, one day, we will all be dead and gone and there is no point to getting too worked up over the mistakes of others in this short time we spend waiting for that inevitable future.

Comment: Well, *that* was some unexpected nihilism...

Comment: I've been reading too much twitter. Too many people willing to die on every hill they find... Willing to build hills when they can't find one handy. It's... very tiring. Nihilism is positively cheerful by comparison.

Comment: I'm awfully tempted to edit in a warning about the dangers of fatalistic resignation.

Comment: You need to get a phone with [night shift](https://xkcd.com/2112/). Really useful. We should probably have it installed in meta as well.

Comment: @Makoto well, not really unexpected considering the OP's username.

Comment: At least [everyone still has their toes](https://gfycat.com/soupyfirstequestrian)